# Modify data.frames differently named through loop

Tags: r

I have an excell file with 4 sheets. I am planning on making a script allowing me to modify them throught loop because some modification will apply to all sheets and some of them not.

I started with loading data and naming each of data.frame with a name of a sheet.

```
## Parameters ##
var_data_name <- "Random data.xlsx" 
var_number_of_data <- 4
var_data_names <- c("Tim", "Jack", "Tom", "Jerry")

for(i in 1:var_number_of_data){
  assign(paste("MS_data", var_data_names[i], sep = "_"), MS_data <- read.xlsx(var_data_name, sheetIndex = i))
}
```

I do it within a loop because number of sheets/data.frames may change and I would like to set it at the begining.

Then my problem starts. I would like to start modyfing them and I have no idea how to "call" them "refer" to them. No idea even how to say it in english. For example in each of formed data frames I would like to remove first and last column. Next, I have some specific modifications for each of data frame, like lets crop/take only first 10 rows from data.frame1 and 11-20 rows from data.frame2, 21-30 rows from data.frame3, etc.

I think that I will manage it as soon as I realize how to refer to all of formed data frames or how to refer to a specific one.

Lets assume that all of sheets have the same content just different names to avoid `dputing` all of them.

```
> dput(MS_data_Jack)
structure(list(NA. = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 
61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72), Sample.Name = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 
68, 69, 70, 71, 72), Sample.ID = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), Sample.Type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = "Unknown", class = "factor"), File.Name = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Data", class = "factor"), 
    Intensity = c(7520, 7770, 11300, 3400, 1750, 2230, 1270, 
    1830, 1400, 773, 308, 858, 1430, 672, 801, 501, 486, 300, 
    243, 215, 415, 243, 186, 243, 329, 415, 401, 415, 286, 486, 
    787, 558, 544, 258, 215, 300, 343, 258, 300, 358, 229, 315, 
    300, 222, 186, 236, 300, 687, 858, 272, 544, 315, 401, 343, 
    386, 243, 558, 215, 429, 458, 1570, 1950, 2370, 601, 644, 
    615, 615, 272, 272, 286, 200, 415), Height = c(2210, 1720, 
    3080, 1030, 802, 360, 477, 401, 372, 361, 130, 490, 291, 
    225, 320, 187, 236, 125, 100, 105, 140, 209, 260, 262, 221, 
    261, 203, 340, 181, 381, 460, 301, 142, 260, 142, 262, 201, 
    151, 120, 300, 101, 141, 144, 105, 107, 176, 201, 241, 285, 
    262, 144, 160, 241, 263, 123, 206, 221, 142, 140, 280, 822, 
    454, 621, 201, 220, 454, 300, 185, 161, 120, 141, 211), Random = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "N/A", class = "factor"), 
    Standard = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "N/A", class = "factor"), Record = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Modify = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Count = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Data = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "N/A", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-72L))
```

Comment: you can get them in one list using `mget(ls(pattern = '^MS_data'))`.

Comment: That is a possible solution but it "forces" me to work with list and I have never done it before. Sounds a bit complicated. Can you give me an expample how to remove specific columns from each data frame through list ?  I guess it has to be done using `lapply`.

Comment: lists are actually easy to manage. Let's say if you want to remove 1st and 3rd column from each dataframe you could do `lapply(mget(ls(pattern = '^MS_data')), function(x) x[-c(1, 3)])`

Comment: Okey, seems like I got it. I tried `LP <- lapply(List_of_data, function(x) x[(names(x) %in% col_to_keep)])` and worked out. I will try to continue this way. Thanks.

Comment: You can also use named lists to help you identify each of the dataframes in your list, rather than having to rely on index position. e.g. `names(List_of_data) <- c("jack", "tom", "tim", "jerry")` to assign names and then e.g. `dim(List_of_data[["jack"]])` to use the dim function on the dataframe in your list named "jack".